# undefined reference yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined, yaml-cpp

I'm on Manjaro Linux using gcc and codelite to compile my code.
It's a project with sfml and yaml-cpp in C++.

My GCC version is 4.9.2 (20150304)

GCC compiler flags are -pg;-g;-O0;-O2;-Wall;-std=c++14

My yaml-cpp version is 0.5.1-1

When I compile I have the followings errors:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  "MyProject.mk"  all'
----------Building project:[ MyProject - Debug ]----------
/usr/bin/g++   -c  "/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/sprite.cpp" -pg -g -O0 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14  -o ./Debug/sprite.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++   -c  "/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/tile.cpp" -pg -g -O0 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14  -o ./Debug/tile.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++   -c  "/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/main.cpp" -pg -g -O0 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++   -c  "/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/grid.cpp" -pg -g -O0 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14  -o ./Debug/grid.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++   -c  "/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/loader.cpp" -pg -g -O0 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14  -o ./Debug/loader.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++  -o ./Debug/MyProject @"MyProject.txt" -L. -L/lib/  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-network -lsfml-audio
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « Mercenaries::Loader::Loader(std::string, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >) »:
/home/myuser/.codelite/MyProject/MyProject/loader.cpp:10: undefined reference to « YAML::LoadFile(std::string const&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::Node::AssignNode(YAML::Node const&) »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:270: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory_holder::merge(YAML::detail::memory_holder&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o:/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: more undefined reference follow to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::Node::AssignNode(YAML::Node const&) »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:270: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory_holder::merge(YAML::detail::memory_holder&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o:/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: more undefined reference follow to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<std::string>(std::string const&, boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:89: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_scalar(std::string const&) »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:35: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_scalar(std::string const&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « convert_to_node<std::basic_string<char> > »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:162: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory_holder::merge(YAML::detail::memory_holder&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<std::string>(std::string const&, boost::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:102: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::insert_map_pair(YAML::detail::node&, YAML::detail::node&) »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:30: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::memory::create_node() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:29: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined() »
./Debug/loader.cpp.o: in function « YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null() »:
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:34: undefined reference to « YAML::detail::node_data::set_null() »
```

Loader.cpp

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "loader.hpp"

namespace Mercenaries
{
    Loader::Loader(std::string config_path, std::vector<std::string> fields_list) : m_config_path(config_path), m_fields_list(fields_list)
    {
        m_config_file = YAML::LoadFile(m_config_path);
    }

    void Loader::parse_file()
    {
        // if the file exist
        if(!m_config_file.IsNull())
        {
            //the first node is the file
            YAML::Node current_node = m_config_file;

            // we get the next node
            YAML::Node node = move_into_node(current_node, "Grid");

            // get the data inside the node
            auto data = node;
        }
        else
        {
            // the file doesn't exist
            std::cout << "Failed to load " << m_config_path << " settings file.";
        }
    }

    YAML::Node Loader::move_into_node(YAML::Node current_node, std::string next_node)
    {
        YAML::Node node;

        // we verify that the node exist
        if(current_node[next_node])
        {
            node = current_node[next_node]; // get the value
        }
        else
        {
            // the node doesn't exist in the yaml file
            std::cout << next_node << " node is not found in " << m_config_path << " goal file";
        }

        return(node);
    }
}
```

Loader.hpp

```
#ifndef DEF_LOADER
#define DEF_LOADER

#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

namespace Mercenaries
{
    class Loader
    {
        public:
            Loader(std::string config_path, std::vector<std::string> fields_list);
            void parse_file();
            YAML::Node move_into_node(YAML::Node current_node, std::string next_node);

        private:
            std::string m_config_path;
            YAML::Node m_config_file;
            std::vector<std::string> m_fields_list;
    };
}

#endif
```

Do you think that it's an yaml-cpp issue ?

Is there an error in my code that make it bug ?

Should I report it if it's a yaml issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not linking to yaml-cpp; you need to add the argument `-lyaml-cpp` (to the command that begins `/usr/bin/g++  -o ./Debug/MyProject`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering a `CMakeLists.txt` project ...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Test_yaml_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
# In case of third party library
#find_package(yaml-cpp PATHS ./thirparty/yaml-cpp/build)

# In case of installed library
find_package(yaml-cpp)
add_executable(yaml_exec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(yaml_exec yaml-cpp)
```

In case of the third-party approach, the `yaml-cpp` library should be already built inside `build` folder and recommended by their documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Try add following to your `cmakelist`:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
```